# What disease does my Japanese cypress (Chamaecyparis obtusa) have?

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, pest-control, bonsai, spider-mites

I got this Japanese cypress (Chamaecyparis obtusa) a month ago and cut it into a bonsai shape. I am new to caring for bonsais or cypresses. I was wondering what these little strings on my new plant's leaves might be.
I thought about spider mites at first, but I heard they create thin webs that are sticky to the touch and little mites can be seen through a magnifying glass. However, My plant's webs are not stick. They feel more like fibers of a fabric and I can't seem so see any small mites. But I have never seen spider mites on a plant before so I might be mistaken.

If anyone has seen this before or has a good idea what it could be, I will be grateful for any advice.

[[image: Leave of my cypress][1]]

[![Leave of my crpress2[[image: ][2][2]2]

Comment: You're right, not spider mites, maybe harmless fiber from the plant. No harm in giving it a soapy shower, though. And you *can see* spider mites moving without a glass.

Comment: I thought it might be harmless at first, too. However, the fibers have increased in density over the past month and I can’t explain their origin.